# Program flow when handling exception PLSQL

Tags: stored-procedures, exception, plsql, oracle10g

My stored procedure looks like follows:

```
  sqlQuery := 'DROP INDEX idArchivoIndex';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;

  EXCEPTION --En caso de que no exista el índice capturamos la excepcion
    WHEN index_not_exists THEN NULL; --y la ignoramos

  sqlQuery := 'CREATE INDEX idArchivoIndex'||
              ' ON '||qusuario||' (id_archivo)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;

  doresetvalidacion(qusuario, idarchivo);

  IF (tipoDependencia = 'PEC') THEN
    dovalidapec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  ELSIF (tipoDependencia = 'SAGARPA') THEN
    dovalidacionpec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
```

If the exception is not raised the procedure just drops the index but no index is recreated ! I thought that this part of the code

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN index_not_exists THEN NULL;
```

Handled the error and then continue with the code below it. Now that I see the results what's after the `EXCEPTION` is executed if and only if the exception was raised.

What I want is to simplify my code, I don't want to copy-paste the same block of code before the `EXCEPTION` clause just to make it work as I expect. Is there a way to achieve it? Maybe with a nested `BEGIN ... END` block? Or will I have to make a separate procedure to reuse code?

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DOVALIDAINFORMACION 
(
  QARCHIVO IN VARCHAR2
, QUSUARIO IN VARCHAR2
, QANIOFISCAL IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  imprimirMensajes CHAR;
  tipoDependencia VARCHAR2(25);
  idArchivo NUMBER;
  sqlQuery VARCHAR2(100);
  index_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(index_not_exists, -1418);
BEGIN

  sqlQuery := 'DROP INDEX idArchivoIndex';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;
  ----------------------
  EXCEPTION --En caso de que no exista el índice capturamos la excepcion
    WHEN index_not_exists THEN --y la ignoramos
      NULL;
  END;
  ----------------------
  sqlQuery := 'CREATE INDEX idArchivoIndex'||
              ' ON '||qusuario||' (id_archivo)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;

  doresetvalidacion(qusuario, idarchivo);

  IF (tipoDependencia = 'PEC') THEN
    dovalidapec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  ELSIF (tipoDependencia = 'SAGARPA') THEN
    dovalidacionpec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;

END DOVALIDAINFORMACION;
```

But can't compile the procedure.

```
Error(32,3): PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "SQLQUERY"
Error(33,48): PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ";" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_    LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || member SUBMULTISET_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that are just missing an extra `BEGIN` in your updated code.  An `EXCEPTION` clause always matches to a `BEGIN` and an `END`.  In the code that you posted, the `EXCEPTION` matches the procedure's `BEGIN`.  You need it to match the `BEGIN` of the nested PL/SQL block.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE DOVALIDAINFORMACION 
(
  QARCHIVO IN VARCHAR2
, QUSUARIO IN VARCHAR2
, QANIOFISCAL IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  imprimirMensajes CHAR;
  tipoDependencia VARCHAR2(25);
  idArchivo NUMBER;
  sqlQuery VARCHAR2(100);
  index_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(index_not_exists, -1418);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    sqlQuery := 'DROP INDEX idArchivoIndex';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;
  EXCEPTION --En caso de que no exista el índice capturamos la excepcion
    WHEN index_not_exists THEN --y la ignoramos
      NULL;
  END;

  sqlQuery := 'CREATE INDEX idArchivoIndex'||
              ' ON '||qusuario||' (id_archivo)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlQuery;

  doresetvalidacion(qusuario, idarchivo);

  IF (tipoDependencia = 'PEC') THEN
    dovalidapec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  ELSIF (tipoDependencia = 'SAGARPA') THEN
    dovalidacionpec(qusuario,qaniofiscal,idarchivo,imprimirMensajes);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END DOVALIDAINFORMACION;
```

As an aside, it seems odd to drop and then immediately re-create an index in a PL/SQL block.  If this is somehow related to your question about [recreating an index after a load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230410/recreate-index-after-delete-load), I'm afraid that you may have misunderstood my answer.  In my earlier answer, I was pointing out that it may be more efficient to drop the index, load your 10 million rows of data, and then re-create the index.  Assuming that the loads are happening in the stored procedure calls you are making in this code, you would want the index to be re-created *after* the loads are complete.

Comment: Ok. That explains a lot. I actually misunderstood. I gotta correct it. Anyway, let's say for some reason I need to do that. I update my question with what you suggested but there are some errors.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. And also follow your advise on the other thread.